# Could user names appear at the top of the question and answer?

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, information-display

Sometimes you want to see who wrote something and if the question or answer is long, then you must scroll down quite a ways. I was wondering if the user name, their avatar, rep count etc. could be placed at the top instead of the bottom.

What do other people think? I can see the opinion that it's bad to judge a question or answer based on who asked it but it's also nice to know if the person is authoritative.

Comment: Initial feeling is plain No, but if you can come with a mockup maybe it can help change this initial feeling. :)

Comment: _"but it's also nice to know if the person is authoritative."_ That's the thing though: the user stamp itself says nothing about whether the person is authoritative, unless you might recognise their name and they're authoritative in the industry. If you saw an answer to a C# question from someone named Eric Lippert who had 23 reputation, would you dismiss it? In the SE I use frequently, _rarely_ is any one 'authoritative'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is about the content and not the users. So this  info is not important to show it on top.

Comment: If so, then why show the user name and their rep at all?

Comment: Because if something is not the main interest does not mean one should remove it at all.